# dynamically changing the size of string array keeping contents same

Tags: c++

```
string *level_two;
```

I got this array declared in the class. I allocated its size dynamically in a class function.

```
level_two = new string [size];
```

I need to change its size mainly increase the size retaining the contents, like if size was 5 and my array is declared dynamically as size of 5 and has some string at location 2 and location 3 I want to increase the size of it to 10 depending upon change in size where the strings at location 2 and 3 should be there too without change.

How can I achieve that?

PART II:

```
int temp=0;
                temp= final_hash_index_one; 

                final_hash_index_one = sum % number_of_keys_to_be_hashed;
                sum = 0;
                cout<<"final_hash_index_one: "<<final_hash_index_one<<endl;
                if(final_hash_index_one>temp)
                {
                    string *tmp = new string[final_hash_index_one+1];
                    std::copy(level_two, tmp, final_hash_index_one+1);
                    delete [] level_two;
                    level_two = tmp;
                }
                if(temp>final_hash_index_one)
                {
                    string *tmp = new string[temp+1];
                    std::copy(level_two, tmp, final_hash_index_one+1);
                    delete [] level_two;
                    level_two = tmp;
                }


                level_two = new string [final_hash_index_one+1];
                level_two[final_hash_index_one] = file_se_uthao;
                tab_obj[return_structure_index].z = level_two;
```

Comment: what difference will it make ??

Comment: @Mat who says it's not std::string?  Besides, you do have to worry about memory allocation when using arrays of std::string.

Comment: With arrays, you can't *increase the size*, because arrays have to be stored in adjacent memory spaces, so you can only set its size at creation with `new`. As @Oli answered, you'd be better with std containers.

Answer (score 7):

**Canonical C++ answer:**

Use a `std::vector<string>`<sup>1</sup> rather than doing manual memory management (i.e. don't use `new` and `delete`). e.g.:

```
std::vector<std::string> level_two(size);

...

level_two[0] = some_string;

...

level_two.resize(different_size);
```

You can also avoid explicit sizing entirely:

```
std::vector<std::string> level_two;

...

level_two.push_back(some_string);
level_two.push_back(other_string);
level_two.push_back(another_string);
...
```

**C-with-classes answer:**

You will need to create a new array, transfer the contents, and then delete the old one:

```
string *tmp = new string[different_size];
std::copy(level_two, level_two+size, tmp);
delete [] level_two;
level_two = tmp;
```

---

<sub>1. Or a `std::list` or whatever else, depending on your requirements.</sub>

Comment: @HarisRiaz: `level_two` is just a pointer.  So `level_two = tmp` just changes where the pointer is pointing to.

Comment: @Haris No, the newly created array, *tmp* is already sized at creation. `level_two = tmp` just makes level_two point to the newly created array.

Comment: i read somewhere a long time back that realloc can also help dealing with change in sizes ??

Comment: @HarisRiaz: Don't use `realloc` in C++; it's incompatible with `new` and `delete`, and it certainly doesn't play well with non-trivial user-defined types.

Comment: string *tmp = new string[different_size];
std::copy(level_two, tmp, size);
delete [] level_two;
level_two = tmp;

Comment: i tried doing the above operation but if cudnt be done . error was cannot convert from 'std::string' to 'int' !

Comment: @HarisRiaz: There are no ints in my code above!  Why not add your new code to your question, and I'll take a look.

Comment: sir i uploaded my code as the PART II in main question. my objective is to retain the previous value of final_hash_index_one in temp . generate a new value of final_hash_index_one check if the previous final_hash_index_one value was smaller if smaller copy the contents to the array temp and then make new level_two with respect to new final_hash_index_one and then shift contents to level_two again . i hope you got what am trying to do! where am i wrong

Comment: @HarisRiaz: Ah, I see.  It turns out the code snippet in my answer wasn't correct.  I've updated it now (notice the arguments to `std::copy` have changed).  For more info, see e.g. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy.

Comment: well i see know error now . ill debug and check now and then acknowledge!! thank you =)

Comment: std::copy(level_two, level_two+(final_hash_index_one+1), tmp);               am having an exception . it says invalid null pointer! what could be the problem??

Comment: string *tmp = new string[some_size];
string *level_two = new string[some_size];    

how to copy contents from level_two to tmp??? in case of string one; string two . we can copy the string through loop. but what in this case??

Comment: @HarisRiaz: If you're having this many issues with it, you should stop and use a container (like a `std::vector`) instead of raw arrays.

Comment: sir i havent used containers yet in my programming practice so right now am following this!